# Serial.print array displays nothing

Tags: programming, debugging

I tried Serial.print an array I had made, but the Arduino displays nothing in the monitor.

I tried doing Serial.print("Hehehe"); as a test, but it just displayed "h?h?h?".

The monitor works fine with other sketches than this one.

Anyone knows why?

```
int my_array[10];

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    my_array[i] = i * 5;

  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      Serial.print(my_array[i]);
      Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: do you have 9600 baud set in Serial Monitor?

Comment: @Juraj I have set it to 9600.

Comment: In setup() you write to undefined memory `my_array[10]`. It's undefined if that hurts or not.

Comment: @DataFiddler I don't quite understand.

The sequence is filled in the function that takes i + 5.

Comment: `i < 11` it should be 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test on my Arduino Uno, your code works fine with a simple copy-paste. Remember to set the proper baud rate.

Comment: Must be something faulty with my own Arduino then. Thank you for the answer though :)

Comment: Load a blink sketch and check if the blink speed is correct. (Should have accuracy of at least 1/1000).